# How to print the values of findElements() of Selenium wrapper for Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, selenium

First of all, I know that `findElements()` returns a list of the values found by Selenium. I would like to know how to print each items in Excel VBA or how it should be printed in Selenium wrapper syntax?

Please see my Code below.

I receive an error something like

> Object does not support....."

at the msgBox syntax.

```
Dim tableElement As WebElement

Set tableElement = driver.FindElementById("picker_address_table_tag")

Dim tableList As New List

Set tableList = tableElement.FindElementById("picker_address_thead").FindElementsByTagName("th")

Dim testString As Variant

testString = tableList.Values()


MsgBox testString(2)

MsgBox testString(3)

MsgBox testString(4)

MsgBox tableList.Count

MsgBox tableList.Item(1).Attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

You should get a collection of `IWebElement` objects:

https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement.htm

So maybe something like:

```
Dim e
'....
For Each e in tableList
    Debug.Print e.Text 'output innerText
Next e
```

Comment: Hi Tim! Thank you very much for the answer. I was able to print out and check the text it outputs.